# SendGrid Send Email Rate Limit

Tags: sendgrid

SendGrid documentation explicitly mentions rate limits on all resources [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/How_To_Use_The_Web_API_v3/rate_limits.html). The send api (`https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send`) doesn't seem to include any `X-RateLimit` headers in its response.

Does this mean that the send api is not rate limited?

Answer (score 8):

It seems so. The docs do no mention any specific endpoint when mentioning rate limits, [see here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/How_To_Use_The_Web_API_v3/rate_limits.html)

I made a request to `https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send` and got no `X-Rate-Limit` header, but a request to `https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/scopes`
got me:

`X-Ratelimit-Limit: 600
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 599
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1492362540`

Also, most if not all libraries do not seem to take rate limit into account. If you write your own code maybe you should, the docs mention returning `429` HTTP status code when rate limit is reached. You should write your code in such a way that it waits for the `X-Ratelimit-Reset` before making another request.

Comment: I just got a response from SendGrid support. They don't limit the send API. It should be pointed out in their docs.

Comment: In case anyone comes here and is confused by this it seems SendGrid have differing rate limits for the type of request.

Answer (score 3):

There is no rate limit for the V2 and above mail/send endpoint.

The default for [SendGrid V2](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/using-the-v2-api/#rate-limits) and above APIs is 600 request per minute, but some APIs are much lower.

Most of SendGrid's other APIs are now rate limited. They have added notes in the [Using the V2 API article](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/using-the-v2-api/#rate-limits) but they still do not reference specific rate limits in the API documentation.